# Saving contents of NSTextView with graphics

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

Thanks for the help. I need to save my RTF's with graphics. The following works fine for text. What do I need to do to make this work with embedded graphics?

thanks again. paul.

```
NSSavePanel *panel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];

[panel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"rtf"]];


NSString *outputName = @"Output File";


[panel setCanCreateDirectories:YES];
[panel setCanSelectHiddenExtension:YES];
[panel setNameFieldStringValue:outputName];




[panel beginSheetModalForWindow:theSwatch completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {

    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton){


        [[textView RTFFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, [[textView string] length])] writeToURL:    [panel URL] atomically:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the NSText method, writeRTFDToFile:atomically:.  Since NSTextView is a subclass of NSText, you should be able to just do this:

```
[textView writeRTFDToFile:[[panel URL] path] atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks. This outputs a folder with an RTF.txt doc and a separate image file. I'm trying to save the contents of the textView including an attached image on a single .rtf file. any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure you can.  What difference does it make if it's a single file or a file package?

Comment: Thanks again. I had the setAllowedFileTypes set to rtf. Changed it to rtfd and I'm all set. Again - thanks.